# Adding a class in a module to Cucumber World

Tags: ruby, testing, cucumber, automated-tests

Given I have defined the following modules in my features/support directory

#### apiworld.rb

```
module Api
   class User
       ...
   end
   ...
end
```

and also

#### webworld.rb

```
module Web
   class User
       ...
   end
   ...
end
```

in my env.rb file I have

#### env.rb

```
require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__)+'/webworld')
require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__)+'/apiworld')

if ENV['USE_API'] == 1
    World(Api)
else
    World(Web)
end
```

So if I try to use this construct in a step definition like

```
Given /^a user is created$/ do
   @user = User.new
end
```

And run `cucumber`, my ruby interpreter will give me the this output

> uninitialized constant User (NameError)
>        ./features/step_definitions/user_steps.rb:17: [...]

How to make this work? Is there a way or am I thinking i the wrong direction. I am pretty new to ruby - so I don't really know what it can do and what it can not do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `World` for this. `World` is for mixing *methods* into the `self` object in each stepdef.

Instead of this:

```
if ENV['USE_API'] == 1
  World(Api)
else
  World(Web)
end
```

Try this:

```
User = ENV['USE_API'] == 1 ? Api::User : Web::User
```